# Does Expression.ToString() work?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, linq-expressions

I have a generated lambda, but when I want to watch it's like a normal lambda it just doesn't show anything. When I call `expr.Body.ToString()` I get following:

```
{var compareA; ... }
```

But DebugView for expression works fine:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Comparison`1[XLinq.Test.Comparers.CustomComparerTest+Test]>(
    XLinq.Test.Comparers.CustomComparerTest+Test $x,
    XLinq.Test.Comparers.CustomComparerTest+Test $y) {
    .Block(System.Int32 $compareA) {
        $compareA = .Call ($x.A).CompareTo($y.A);
        .If ($compareA != 0) {
            .Return #Label1 { $compareA }
        } .Else {
            .Block(System.Int32 $compareB) {
                $compareB = .Call ($x.B).CompareTo($y.B);
                .If ($compareB != 0) {
                    .Return #Label1 { $compareB }
                } .Else {
                    .Block(System.Int32 $compareC) {
                        $compareC = .Call ($x.C).CompareTo($y.C);
                        .If ($compareC != 0) {
                            .Return #Label1 { $compareC }
                        } .Else {
                            .Block(System.Int32 $compareD) {
                                $compareD = .Call ($x.D).CompareTo($y.D);
                                .If ($compareD != 0) {
                                    .Return #Label1 { $compareD }
                                } .Else {
                                    .Default(System.Void)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        .Label
            0
        .LabelTarget #Label1:
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this result?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because the `Expression.ToString` override relies on the internal `ExpressionStringBuilder` visitor type, which produces a greatly simplified expression tree representation.

The debug view provided by custom debugger proxies defined on each `Expression`-derived type (i.e. `[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(Expression.BlockExpressionProxy))]` on `BlockExpression`) provides a lot more information, as you've found out, by exposing the output of a more verbose `DebugViewWriter` visitor (also internal).

Unfortunately, you can't get that output easily outside of debug scenarios, unless you're willing to use reflection to fetch the value of a private `DebugView` property (defined in `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`) as follows:

```
Expression<Func<string, int>> expr = str => str.Length;
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
PropertyInfo debugViewProp = typeof(Expression).GetProperty("DebugView", flags);
MethodInfo debugViewGetter = debugViewProp.GetGetMethod(nonPublic: true);
string debugView = (string)debugViewGetter.Invoke(expr, null);
```

Produces

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.String,System.Int32]>(System.String $str) {
    $str.Length
}
```

As always, Reference Source is your best friend:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/Microsoft/Scripting/Ast/Expression.cs,aa5f054356a8a17d

Comment: Therefore I'm not able to get string representation of Expression writen in C#? I mean something like `var compareA = x.CompareTo(y); ...`

Comment: Correct, `ToString` only outputs variables declared by the `BlockExpression`. It does not visit inner expressions (they are represented by "..."). You can use a third-party package to do what you want (ExpressionToCode being one example - I do not endorse it, but a quick test indicates that it gets the job done, albeit without any indenting). Alternatively you can roll your own visitor - similar to writing an `IQueryable` provider.

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy I've written a [library which provides a better C# representation](https://github.com/zspitz/ExpressionTreeToString), as well as other formats, such as factory method calls.