# Runtime generated expression cannot change dictionary's values

Tags: c#, .net-core, expression-trees, c#-8.0, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to create some expression at runtime to change a given dictionary's values. I created this snippet which generates the expression successfully and compiles it an `Action`. But calling the action cannot modify dictionary's value, and also doesn't throw any error. Here is the code:

```
public class ChangeDicValue {

    public void Change(IDictionary<string, object> dic) {
        var blocks = MakeCleaningBlock(dic);
        foreach (var block in blocks) 
            block.Invoke(dic);
    }

    private List<Action<IDictionary<string, Object>>> MakeCleaningBlock(IDictionary<string , object > dic) {

        var allKeys = dic.Keys.ToArray();

        var dicType = typeof(IDictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string), typeof(object));

        var dicContainsMethod = dicType.GetMethod("ContainsKey", new[] {typeof(string)})
                                ?? throw new InvalidOperationException();

        var actions = new List<Action<IDictionary<string, Object>>>();

        ParameterExpression actionArguments =
            Expression.Parameter(dicType, "actionArguments");

        foreach (var k in allKeys) {

            Expression key = Expression.Constant(k, typeof(string));

            Expression target = Expression.Property(actionArguments, "Item", key);

            var innerStatements = new List<Expression>(Changers);

            var cleanStatements = new List<Expression>();

            foreach (var ins in innerStatements) {
                var assign = Expression.Assign(target, Expression.Block(ins, target));

                cleanStatements.Add(assign);
            }

            Expression body1 = Expression.Block(new List<Expression>(cleanStatements) {target});

            var callToContains = Expression.Call(actionArguments, dicContainsMethod, key);
            var ifThenBody     = Expression.IfThen(callToContains, body1);

            var cleanedValueBlock = Expression.Block(target, ifThenBody, target);

            var assignDic = Expression.Assign(target, cleanedValueBlock);
            // see the debug view of assignDic in UPDATE

            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Action<IDictionary<string, Object>>>(assignDic, actionArguments);

            var method = lambda.Compile();

            actions.Add(method);
        }

        return actions;
    }


    private static readonly Expression<Func<object, string>>[] Changers
        = {
            s => s + " First changer added.", 
            s => s + " Second changer added."
        };

}
```

As you can see, it's a pretty simple code and causen't any error. Do you have any idea what I missed?

**EDIT:**

The debug view of variable `assignDic` for one item in a sample dictionary:

```
$actionArguments.Item["a"] = .Block() {
    $actionArguments.Item["a"];
    .If (
        .Call $actionArguments.ContainsKey("a")
    ) {
        .Block() {
            $actionArguments.Item["a"] = .Block() {
                .Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.Object,System.String]>;
                $actionArguments.Item["a"]
            };
            $actionArguments.Item["a"] = .Block() {
                .Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[System.Object,System.String]>;
                $actionArguments.Item["a"]
            };
            $actionArguments.Item["a"]
        }
    } .Else {
        .Default(System.Void)
    };
    $actionArguments.Item["a"]
}

.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[System.Object,System.String]>(System.Object $s) {
    $s + " First changer added."
}

.Lambda #Lambda2<System.Func`2[System.Object,System.String]>(System.Object $s) {
    $s + " Second changer added."
}
```

Comment: Why do you build an `Expression` and calls `Invoke()` on it instead of just using the `Func<>` objects you defined at the end directly or build the `Action` statements directly? What makes you require to use build an `Expression` object?

Comment: @Progman It's part of a bigger code which makes me build some actions (as changers) at runtime based on different dictionaries.

Comment: And you can't build an `Action` by yourself with something like `Action<...> action = dict => { foreach (var entry in dict) { if (something.ContainsKey(entry.Item)) { ... } } ...` (depending on what the code should do)? Might be easier to read/maintain than to build `Expression` objects.

Comment: @Progman Unfortunately no. It's not possible.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the `DebugView` of the expression you are building (as mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34116591/does-expression-tostring-work and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51776624/how-can-you-render-an-object-similar-to-the-debugview-property-available-when-de)? It might get some insight of how the expression has been build and if it does make sense.

Comment: The code is not pretty simply and is hard to read and understand. Especially the `Expression.Assign` with right operand being block. Most likely that's the problem.

Comment: @Progman I edited the question and added a debug view.

Comment: @IvanStoev seems simple to me. Nothing special is in code. I'm agree with you that the assign expression couses the problem. But cannot figure it out how to resolve.

Comment: It would help if you show in plain c# code what are you trying to generate. e.g. for each key in dictionary invoke several lambda expressions against the dictionary value and store it back?

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks to the help and mentions. Found the problem & solution. See the answer I posted. thanks again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. Finally I found the problem & solution. The break point of the code was on the assignment in the inner `foreach` loop, where I was trying to assign an `Expression.Block` to a `IndexerExpression`. It seems `block`ing an expression won't call it. So, I changed it to an `InvokationExpression` by calling `Expression.Invoke` and passing the `IndexerExpression` (named `target`) and now it works like a charm:

```
foreach (var ins in innerStatements) {
    var assign = Expression.Assign(target, Expression.Invoke(ins, target));
    cleanStatements.Add(assign);
}
```